# Does the Mongo shell have any function equivalent to setInterval?

Tags: mongodb, function, setinterval

Does the Mongo shell have any function equivalent to setInterval in the web browsers?

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Reason is that I would like to be able to delay between two shell calls and measure amount of activity within elapsed time. I am able to use the 2.4 and 2.6 shells.

Comment: I don't think so. but you can always use [cron](http://www.pantz.org/software/cron/croninfo.html) to ran a small shell script periodically.

Comment: Agreed - I don't think such a function exists in the mongo shell. You can find a listing of a lot of the [mongo-shell specific functions](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/) in the MongoDB Manual, for future reference.

Comment: I've accomplished this by calling mongo command within while loop like:
`while :; do mongo db-name --quiet --eval "db.users.count({ active: true })"; sleep 5; done`

Adjust interval in `sleep 5` to your liking. One difference is seconds you give in sleep command is added to mongo command's execution time.